# How to connect data from Oracle database to Kendo Grid using Java?

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, kendo-grid

I could able to create a grid using local data. I want to know how to get data from Oracle database to display as a Kendo Grid?

How to modify "read" function in datasource to get data?

**Servlet**

```
public class TeacherListPageServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    ArrayList<MessageObjects> listArr;
    OracleConnection oraconn= new OracleConnection();
    listArr= oraconn.teacherDetails();

    System.out.println("In teacher servlet \n" );

    if(!listArr.isEmpty()){
    Gson gson= new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(listArr);
    System.out.println("In list");
    System.out.println(json);

    request.setAttribute("list",json);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Grid.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //response.sendRedirect("Grid.jsp");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("list is empty");
    }

}
```

}

*listArr= oraconn.teacherDetails();* will call OracleConnection.java

**OracleConnection**

```
public  ArrayList teacherDetails()
{
ArrayList<MessageObjects> list= new ArrayList<MessageObjects>();
ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<>();
MessageObjects obj= new MessageObjects();
try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","STUDENT_DB","Aishwarya11");
        Statement statement=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery("select * from TEACHERS_DETAILS");
        while(rs.next()) {
        obj.setTid(rs.getString(1));
        obj.setName(rs.getString(2)); 
        obj.setGender(rs.getString(3));
        obj.setDob(rs.getString(4)) ;
        obj.setYoe(rs.getString(5)) ;
        obj.setMajsub(rs.getString(6));
        list.add(obj);
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        String json=gson.toJson(obj);
        System.out.println("In DAO");
        System.out.println(json);
        list1.add(json);
        System.out.println("List1");

             } 

    }
  catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  return list1;

 }
```

Forwarding data from servlet to jsp(Grid.jsp)

**Grid.jsp**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport:{
                read:{/* I want to know how to read data here , how to code ?*/,
                     dataType : "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     }


                },

            schema:{
                data: "xdata.rows",
                model:{
                    id:"tid",
                      fields:{
                          //     tid:{editable:false},

                            tid:{type:"String"},
                            name:{type:"String"},
                            gender:{type:"String"},
                            dob:{type:"String"},
                            yoe:{type:"String"},
                            majsub:{type:"String"}

                      }
                }
         },
         pageSize:20,
         batch:true
        });


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
               dataSource:dataSource,
               height:350,

               scrollable: true,
               columns:[{field: "tid",title:"Teacher Id",width: "130px"},
                        {field: "name",title:"Name",width: "130px"},
                        {field: "gender",title:"Gender",width: "130px" },
                        {field: "dob",title:"Date of Birth",width: "130px"},
                        {field: "yoe",title:"Year of Experience",width: "130px"},
                        {field: "majsub",title:"Major sub",width: "130px" },

                        {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                        editable: "popup"
               });
        });
```

- I am just trying to read data to grid, so i didn't provide Update,Destroy,Create.
- I successfully retrieve data from Database and changed it to JSON.

> ["{\"tid\":\"001\",\"name\":\"Varalakshmi\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"dob\":\"01/08/1989\",\"yoe\":\"2\",\"majsub\":\"Physics\"}","{\"tid\":\"002\",\"name\":\"Lakshman\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"dob\":\"05/08/1979\",\"yoe\":\"8\",\"majsub\":\"Maths\"}"]

I got this in Grid.jsp, when i tried to view it using

> ${list}

Comment: kendo grid needs data in json form, provide data in json to your grid

Comment: I create my data in JSON format, but i want to know how to pass it in read function for grid.

Comment: First create dataSource and then bind it with kendo grid, please find the answer below. You can also check on kendo website for better reference,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data you are passing is not in correct json format.
Compare the changedData and yourData in the method.

Data is required in array form for Grid, that's why I am converting it into array form. If you have data in array then pass that directly.
that should be like :

```
var data5 = [{ "Id": 121, "referenceId": 18222, "status": "test", "message": 'kk', "ss": "ss" }, { "Id": 121, "referenceId": 18222, "status": "test", "message": 'kk', "ss": "ss" }, { "Id": 121, "referenceId": 18222, "status": "test", "message": 'kk', "ss": "ss" }];
```

You will need  kendo js and css file for kendo grid.

Use these :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.material.min.css">

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-editable" style="height: 550px;">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var yourData = ["\"tid\":\"001\",\"name\":\"Varalakshmi\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"dob\":\"01/08/1989\",\"yoe\":\"2\",\"majsub\":\"Physics\"}", "{\"tid\":\"002\",\"name\":\"Lakshman\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"dob\":\"05/08/1979\",\"yoe\":\"8\",\"majsub\":\"Maths\"}"]
                var changedData = "[{\"tid\":\"001\",\"name\":\"Varalakshmi\",\"gender\":\"Female\",\"dob\":\"01/08/1989\",\"yoe\":\"2\",\"majsub\":\"Maths\"}, {\"tid\":\"002\",\"name\":\"Lakshman\",\"gender\":\"Male\",\"dob\":\"05/08/1979\",\"yoe\":\"8\",\"majsub\":\"Maths\"}]";
                var feedData = $.parseJSON(changedData);

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: feedData,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    //  toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                    columns: [
                         { field: "tid", title: "Unit Price" },
                          { field: "name", title: "Units In Stock" },
                          { field: "gender", title: "gender" },
                          { field: "dob", title: "dob" },
                          { field: "yoe", title: "yoe" },
                          { field: "majsub", title: "majsub" },
                    ],

                    editable: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to explain. I will change my question details by adding my code in it.  check it and guide me to make some changes. i will update my question details soon.

Comment: Hi. I updated my question details. Can you please help me further?

Comment: Can you tell me, how your list looks like before converting into json, you use that directly

Comment: I tried to give data directly in changedData and it works fine, Thank you & I am getting data in array format as you mentioned, before converting it to JSON. I have that data in Servlet Page. How to bind it in `var` for grid. _listArr_ contains `[{"tid":"001","name":"Varalakshmi","gender":"Female","dob":"01/08/1989","yoe":"2","majsub":"Physics"}, {"tid":"002","name":"Lakshman","gender":"Male","dob":"05/08/1979","yoe":"8","majsub":"Maths"}]`   I tried to import servlet in jsp to access it, and also tried with `kendo.template("#= listArr #");` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you are getting data in array form then go with it, its like var data = [{"tid":"001","name":"Varalakshmi"}, {"tid":"001","name":"Varalakshmi"}]. Are you able to see your those data in kendo grid ?

Comment: Yes i can see data in Grid when i give it directly in jsp like var data=[{"tid":"001" .....},{"tid":"002" .....}]

Comment: means your problem is solved now ? If yes you can mark my answer as correct, else please let me know. If you are getting not in the format you need then try converting it into using jquery functions like $.parseJSON or makeArray function, that will change your data in the required form.

Comment: I create a new ArrayList in jsp and get data from servlet then read it in kendo using <%=listAns%> . Worked fine. Thanks for your help spark. :)